# PHP: What is the error in the foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, increment

I am trying to avoid using array_count_values (too slow) to count occurrences, so I am using a foreach loop but I keep getting this error message below even though the result prints correctly!!!

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in on line 5
PHP Stack trace:

```
$somearray=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2);
$frequency=array();
foreach($somearray as $key => $val) {
        $frequency[$somearray[$key]]++; //THIS IS LINE 5
    }

print_r($frequency);
```

It prints correctly despite all thrown error messages:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1
)
```

Comment: Well, you're starting with an empty array, so there is no `0` index until you set it.

Comment: It's not an error, it's only a notice. PHP is saying "hey, you're trying to increment something that doesn't exist, so I'm just going to assume an initial value of 0" -- which happens to be exactly what you want.

Comment: See if the array key exists first. If not, initialize it.

Comment: I'm curious, why would this way be faster than `array_count_values`? Have you done some testing to verify that it is? How large is the actual array you're dealing with? (I assume it's much larger than the example here if speed has become a problem.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic I am trying to test it now to see if it is faster than array_count_values when you are using millions of numbers. My script is handling 2 million numbers and array_count_values is the pig that slows it down.

Comment: I see. I would think the built-in function would still be faster, but we'll see. It's an interesting problem! The numbers aren't coming from a database, are they? Seems like group by + count would probably be more efficient in that case. I would also suggest, if you have a fixed range of values in the input array, to initialize your output array with zero counts for each value before the loop to avoid the isset check in each iteration.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, you were right the built in function was much faster! Numbers aren't coming from a database...oh well, I'll continue on with using strings and converting them back to numbers, that has been much faster...just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notice *"Undefined offset: 0"* is verbose, some index was not set before ***infix increment*** operation (in-place addition, `$<var>++`) while a regular assignment won't lead to *notice*.

To suppress *Notice*:

```
...
@$frequency[$val]++;
```

---

To **avoid** *Notice*:

```
...
$frequency[$val] = (isset($frequency[$val]))? $frequency[$val]+1 : 1;
```

The **good** practice is to avoid notices, warnings, errors ...